# Including a module in other module

Tags: ruby

```
module A; def a; end; end
module B; def b; end; end

class C; include A; end

module A; include B; end
class D; include A; end

C.new.b # undefined method error
D.new.b # nil

C.ancestors # [C, A, Object...]
D.ancestors # [D, A, B, Object...]
```

How to include module B inside of A, so that classes that already include module A will also get methods from module B?

Comment: Ultimately, what do you want to achieve here? Can you illustrate your use case with a concrete example? Maybe your problem can be approached differently.

Comment: I wanted to include my module in `ActionDispatch::Routing::UrlFor` Rails module, so that all Rails classes that include it, would automatically have my new methods as well. I solved it differently, but was quite surprised that it doesn't work this way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't.

When you `include` a mixin `M` into a class `C`, Ruby creates a new class `⟦M′⟧` whose method table points to the method table of the mixin `M` and whose superclass is the superclass of `C`, then makes this class the new superclass of `C`. This is repeated for every mixin that was mixed into `M`.

Note that this algorithm is run only once, when you mix `M` into `C`. Modules that get `include`d later, will not get considered.

Answer (score 3):

As has already been stated, Ruby doesn't work like this - when a class includes a module, it doesn't maintain any reference to the instance of that module so if the module includes other modules, the classes that have already included it won't know about the change.

You could get around this by storing the classes that include the module in the module itself - that way you can update them whenever the module includes another module, i.e. something like this:

```
module A

  class<<self
    attr_accessor :observers
  end

  self.observers = []

  def a
    "#{self} successfully called a"
  end

  def self.included(base)
    self.observers << base unless self.observers.include?(base)
  end

  def self.include(mod)
    observers.each {|o| o.send(:include,mod) }
    super
  end

end

module B
  def b
    "#{self} successfully called b"
  end
end

class C
  include A
end

module A
  include B
end

class D
  include A
end

module E
  def e
    "#{self} successfully called e"
  end
end

module A
  include E
end

puts C.new.b 
puts D.new.b 
puts C.new.e
puts D.new.e
```

Not sure this is the direction you want to take, but shows that it can be done in principle.

Answer (score 1):

You should Include B in A before   **class C; include A; end**.

```
module A; def a; end; end
module B; def b; end; end


module A; include B; end

class C; include A; end
class D; include A; end

p C.new.b # nil
p D.new.b # nil

p C.ancestors # [C, A, B, Object, Kernel, BasicObject]
p D.ancestors # [D, A, B, Object, Kernel, BasicObject]
```

**Edit**

```
module A; def a; end; end
module B; def b; end; end

class C; include A; end

module A; include B; end
class D; include A; end

C.send(:include, A)

p C.new.b # nil
p D.new.b # nil

p  C.ancestors # [C, A, Object...]
p D.ancestors # [D, A, B, Object...]
```

Comment: I can't change the order in which classes include these modules. 

I'm trying to extend Rails `ActionDispatch::Routing::UrlFor` module which is already included in some Rails classes

Comment: Isn't this what `ActiveSupport::Concern` was built for?

Comment: Thanks, but the idea is that I'd like to include my module inside of `ActionDispatch::Routing::UrlFor`, so that all Rails classes that include it would _automatically_ get these new methods. I don't want to iterate over every Rails class that includes this module. If I had a list of all these classes I could simply include my module directly into them.